# NextJS Dynamic Routing, re-render specific Child Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, router, dynamic-routing

I have index.js page, located at

> **pages/posts/index.js**

I can render this page with Link:

```
<Link href={`/posts`} />
```

this is my index.js page:

```
function mainComponent({props}) {
 <>
  <MainComponent>
   <ChildComponent1/>
   <ChildComponent2 props={propsValue}/>
  <MainComponent/>
 </>
}
```

Now, with dynamic routing of NextJs, i want to use query params and call api to get propsValue for

`<ChildComponent2 props={propsValue}>`

I use dynamic routing, with this link:

```
<Link href={/posts/${dynamic-pageId}} />
```

can i Re-Render only **ChildComponent2** with the obtained value propsValue from API?

**Note:** I don't have physical files as **/pages/posts/${dynamic-pageId}**, i want to use that **/pages/posts/index.js**, because i too have to render in this hirerachy:

```
<>
<MainComponent>
 <ChildComponent1/>
 <ChildComponent2 props={propsValue}/>
<MainComponent/>
```

can it be possible in NextJs?

Comment: Is it required to pass props from the main component? You can have posts/[dynamic-pageId].js file which will render your child component and using getStaticProps, you can get the specific props.

Comment: No i have to render that child component inside main component. I have made posts/[dynamic-pageId].js this file. But what to render inside that file?

Comment: You can define you custom server , so that `posts/[id]` will route to `/posts/index.js` file and you can get the `id` as query param in that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the props param changes the component renders with the changed props.

Now since MainComponent is using `children`, we cannot prevent it from re-rendering without an expensive computation which will anyways be an overhead.

However we can prevent the `ChildComponent1` from re-rendering by implementing it as a PureComponent like

```
class ChildComponent1 extends React.PureComponent {}
```

In case your ChildComponent1 is a functional component, you can make use of React.memo to prevent re-rendering if nothing changed for the component

```
const ChildComponent1 = React.memo((props) => {
    // logic here
})
```

Comment: no, my question is how to display that ChildComponent2 with the url: /posts/${dynamic-pageId} inside main component? I want to be specific with NextJs dynamic routing.

Comment: You would be rendering {props.children} within MainComponent right. Or do you only need to show it if the url matches. Also are you using Router?

Comment: I just want to do dynamic routing with that url. I have made file as [id].js file for dynamic file generation. Inside [id].js file getInitialProps() method i try to use query.id to get url params. With that query i hit the api and get data. But that data should be passed to mainComponent and re-render that second child component only. How can we achieve this in NextJs?